# Title of Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync

Tags: office-js

I am using `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myurl', {height: 60, width: 60, displayInIframe: true})` to display a dialog.

How do I change the title so that it does not start with: "Message from Add-in:"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no API to control the dialog title at this time. Please vote up the suggestion at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33035422-allow-to-customize-the-pop-up-dialogue-title-when).

Comment: There's been no change in this issue.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could please suggest a way around for this problem? any alternative dialog tool that works like ui dialog for Word and Outlook add-ins?